# IA-automorphisms of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be any group and $IA(G)$ denote the group of those automorphisms of $G$ which are identity on $G/[G,G]$.

If $G$ is finitely generated *nilpotent* group, then $IA(G)$ is finitely generated. (possibly by P.Hall)

**Question 1.** If $G$ is only finitely generated, can $IA(G)$ be finitely generated?

**Question 2.** What are other conditions on $G$ which ensure that $IA(G)$ is finitely generated?

Answer (score 3):

One of the more famous examples is $G = \pi_1(S)$ where $S$ is a closed, oriented surface of genus $g \ge 3$ in which case $IA(G)$ is the famous Torelli group of genus $g$, finite generation of which is a theorem of Dennis Johnson; see [this paper](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Torelli.pdf) for discussion and references.

Comment: Lee: nice example.